# Combining two queries where one uses GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, aggregate-functions, hiveql

I have two tables. TABLE1 has columns:

```
pers_key
cost
visit
```

TABLE2 has columns:

```
pers_key
months
```

First, I create a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table as
SELECT pers_key,SUM(cost) AS sum_cost, COUNT(DISTINCT visit) AS visit_count
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY pers_key;
```

Then, I create TABLE3:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE3 as
SELECT A.pers_key,
B.sum_cost/A.months AS ind1,
B.visit_count/A.months AS ind2
FROM TABLE2 AS A, temp_table AS B
WHERE A.pers_key = B.pers_key
```

I'm wondering if there is better way to achieve the same result here. Would it be possible to do this in one query without creating temp_table altogether? Perhaps something like:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE3 as
SELECT A.pers_key,
(SUM(B.cost)over (partition by B.pers_key))/A.months AS ind1,
(COUNT(B.visit)over (partition by B.pers_key))/A.months AS ind2
FROM TABLE2 AS A, TABLE1 AS B
WHERE A.pers_key = B.pers_key
```

Or is the temporary table required to achieve the desired result set?

Comment: Have you tried combining them using a union. ie. select Col1, Col2 from table1 union select Col1, Col2 from table2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using a subquery?

```
SELECT A.pers_key,
       B.sum_cost / A.months AS ind1,
       B.visit_count / A.months AS ind2
FROM TABLE2 A JOIN
     (SELECT pers_key, SUM(cost) AS sum_cost,
             COUNT(DISTINCT visit) AS visit_count
      FROM TABLE1
      GROUP BY pers_key
     ) B
     ON A.pers_key = B.pers_key;
```

EDIT:

Your question is a bit complicated.  This is definitely a *reasonable* approach.  It may be faster to put the subquery in a table and build an index on the table for the join.  However, a red flag is the `count(distinct)`.  In my experience with Hive, the following is faster than the above subquery:

```
     (SELECT pers_key, SUM(sum_cost) AS sum_cost,
             COUNT(visit) AS visit_count
      FROM (SELECT pers_key, visit, SUM(cost) as sum_cost
            FROM TABLE1
            GROUP BY pers_key, visit
           ) t
      GROUP BY pers_key
     ) B
```

It is a bit counter-intuitive (to me) that this version is faster.  But, what happens is that the `group by` is that Hive readily parallelizes the `group by`s.  On the other hand, the `count(distinct)` is processed serially.  This sometimes occurs in other databases (I've seen similar behavior in Postgres with `count(distinct)`.  And another caveat:  I did not set up the Hive system where I discovered this, so it might be some sort of configuration issue.

Comment: This is great. One last question. If the tables are both millions of rows, is this the most efficient way to generate the desired result set?

Comment: The count(distinct visit) will force a single reducer.  This is not the most efficient. use a sub query for the distinct: Select count(*), pers_key from (select visit, perskey from table group by perskey, visit) t.